# Use RequireJS to load multiple TypeScript / JavaScript files

Tags: typescript

I've decoupled my main.ts and place each class files into a separate .ts (under the same module). I want to use requirejs to include that module in my dependencies but I have no idea how to do that if the module is divided into multiple .ts/.js.

Thanks,
Mars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but your question is about how to `import` a module that is split across multiple files...

My recommendation in terms of loading these modules is that you create a hierarchy to make the module more like a namespace. Here is an example...

Originally you have `Logging` as a single module. You then split it into multiple files for different flavours of logging. Use the following structure:

```
/Logging/Console.ts
/Logging/File.ts
/Logging/Remote.ts
```

You can then import what you need using:

```
import consoleLogging = module('/Logging/Console');
```

Or

```
import fileLogging = module('/Logging/File');
```

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

I have a video tutorial on that : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AGQpv0MKsA

Basically to reference other ts files from your ts files you simply import them:

```
import otherfile = module('pathtootherfile')
```

The generated JS (when using the `--module amd` flag) does the setup that requireJs demands. It gets more involved when you want to import other JS files and that's covered in the tutorial as well as this sample project : https://github.com/basarat/typescript-amd