# typescript - 250 .ts files - require(), //reference, module, etc

Tags: requirejs, typescript

We are creating a typescript app that will have about 250 classes. Coming from the C# world, we are creating a .ts file for each class. And that feels appropriate as each class/file will be between 20 and 500 lines of code. And it keeps things clean for the object orientation.

Which leads to a couple of questions for all this.

1. Should we have a unique module name per .ts file, per folder, or per
   project (a folder and all its sub folders)?
2. When a class is dependent on other classes, should we wrap that .ts file in a [require/define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079464/whats-the-correct-way-to-use-requirejs-with-typescript) (we use require.js) for the dependencies? Or should we have a single massive require in our root .js file (listing all 250+ files)? Or is there another approach we should use?
3. We are having to put in a ton of /// <reference ... /> statements. Is there a way to have global ones? Or a way to put wild cards in so we can have a single reference call for all .ts files in a folder?
4. Any other suggestions for what we should and should not do for a project this large?

**Update:** This is for a client side app that will run in a browser. We are presently using requirejs. It is a lot of code, but all of the code is needed in the browser (sooner or later).

I want it to be quick/easy to run/debug when coding and then, probably building it differently, have it be fast/small to upload. Half of us develop in WebStorm and half in VisualStudio.

Comment: I think your question is too broad and too subjective. While there are some guidelines, a lot of the answers really depend on how the resulting code will be used. I wouldn't split each TS class into a separate file, especially something that was 20 lines of code. You loose some features, like being able to take advantage of the natural closures that are formed in modules for example.

Comment: You might have a look at this BUILD 2014 video [Surviving Application Scale JavaScript - TypeScript in the Trenches](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-583). The first 7 minutes are skippable.

Comment: @WiredPrairie That video is a great answer to this question - thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should we have a unique module name per .ts file

Yes use amd/commonjs : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

> per folder

Yes create an `index.js` that exports everything from a folder.

> When a class is dependent on other classes, should we wrap that .ts file in a require/define (we use require.js) for the dependencies?

no. Use the built in `import` statement in TypeScript

> We are having to put in a ton of ///  statements. Is there a way to have global ones?

Yes look at `reference files` https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#reference-file-generation

> Any other suggestions for what we should and should not do for a project this large?

Depend on TypeScript as much as you can and then refactoring to a different pattern will not be too hard when one emerges (you should get compile errors)

Comment: I don't think he provided enough information to form a proper answer. It's not even tagged with a browser or NodeJS. How modules are named depends a lot on team and other organization decisions. Folders sometimes makes for a logical group. But, it shouldn't force it.

Comment: "I don't think he provided enough information to form a proper answer" true ... but I tried my best

Comment: Basarat - thank you, this helps a lot. We're using requireJS. I think you say above first unique module name per file, then unique per folder. Am I not understanding something? On the index.js that holds everything from a folder, is that just to make the load time faster? Because that adds a step (I think) every time we build to debug. Thank you for the video, "use import" and grunt suggestions - those all help a lot.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I added an update that I think answers your question. I realize it is sort of general but we're learning javascript/typescript with this project and so we don't know what we should list in questions like this. The code is a copy of an existing codebase (in Java) and so we're following the structure/folders/classes we have in that at present.

Comment: Modules are loaded into memory only *once* in RequireJS. The reason for index.js is to make it easier to import all the stuff in a folder if you need e.g. three things from a folder